# Кто такой дед-прошак?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, жаргон, фразеология

Нашел выражение *дед-прошак*, а что такое *прошак* не могу найти. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: Цитату дайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Будьте добры, скажите, где вы нашли это выражение в русскоязычном тексте?

Comment: В соннике, вот ссылка, смотрите в самом нижнем столбике и вы правы, это украинский сонник оказался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошак – украинское диалектное слово, обозначающее "нищий; тот, кто живет на милостыню". Следовательно, дед-прошак – это нищий дед или дед, живущий на милостыню.

Comment: Вообще, *нищий дед* или *дед, живущий на милостыню* звучит странно. И это не вопрос о русском языке.

Comment: Ну если совсем точно, то в русском есть универсальный перевод - "побирушка"... А вот слово "дiд" в украинском может иметь более широкое значение, вплоть до "черта". Так что при поверхностном переводе возможно всякое.

Comment: Есть такое, но это просторечие. Ну тут про деда спрашивают, я про деда отвечаю)

Comment: Примного благодарен, благодарствую вам.